# Not able to use same formula in another cell as it contains column number of that cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to paste a formula but it is not working as expected
For example, I have a formula `=7*B2`
which gives me result 35.
Now I want to use it in lot of other columns in the same sheet. For example I want to it use in 'O' column I am not able to use it. When I do Ctrl + C , Ctrl + V it takes `=7xO2` and return me 0. Only option is copy `=7*B2` text and paste it which unusual way. I tried all Paste option but it is returning me 0

It is fine if I can store value of B and multiplied it by 7 but did not find any such formula

Comment: You have to use an absolute reference: `= 7*$B2`

Comment: Take a look at absolute reference as mentioned above and read from MS Doc **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the cell with $.

if B2 is a fixed location, (example: for TAX%)
then use =7*$B$2

if "B" is a field/column to be multiplied/used with relative/adjacent cells
then use = 7*$B2